# Update column name present in txt file with 0 or 1 in its column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encoding

Want code where I have csv file and txt file I have to update column name present in the txt file with 0 or 1 in its column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
with open("activites1.txt",'r') as fm:
    for line in fm:
        line = line.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
        filt = (df[line] == '1')
        df.loc[filt, line] = '1'
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input of `data.csv`, `activities1.txt` and expected output?

Comment: sir thanks for your reply I have solved the issue thanks